# Generating batches of images in dask

Tags: python, python-3.x, dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I just started with `dask` because it offers great parallel processing power. I have around `40000` images on my disk which I am going to use for building a classifier using some DL library, say `Keras` or `TF`. I collected this meta-info(image path and corresponding label) in a pandas dataframe, which looks like this:

```
    img_path     labels
0   data/1.JPG   1
1   data/2.JPG   1
2   data/3.JPG   5
...
```

Now here is my simple task: Use dask to read images and corresponding labels in a `lazy` fashion. Do some processing on images and pass batches to the classifier in a `batch size` of 32.

1. **Define functions for reading and preprocessing:**

   ```
   def read_data(idx):
       img = cv2.imread(data['img_path'].iloc[idx])
       label = data['labels'].iloc[idx]
       return img, label

   def img_resize(img):
       return cv2.resize(img, (224,224))
   ```
2. **Get delayed dask arrays:**

   ```
   data = [dd.delayed(read_data)(idx) for idx in range(len(df))]
   images = [d[0] for d in data]
   labels = [d[1] for d in data]
   resized_images = [dd.delayed(img_resize)(img) for img in images]
   resized_images = [dd.array.from_delayed(x, shape=(224,224, 3),dtype=np.float32) for x in resized_images]
   ```

Now here are my questions:

Q1. How do I get a `batch` of data, with `batch_size=32` from this array? Is this equivalent to a lazy generator now? If not, can it be made to behave like one?

Q2. How to choose effective `chunksize` for better batch generation? For example, if I have `4` cores, size of images is `(224,224,3)`, how can I make my batch processing efficient?

Comment: This appears to be a double-posting of https://github.com/dask/dask-examples/issues/35#issuecomment-502013307 .  Please do not double-post.  Please read http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/support.html